# Invalid redeclaration in code converting from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm try to convert code from Objective-C to Swift  -

Objc-C part - no errors.

AppDelegate:

```
- (OWTConferenceClient*)conferenceClient{
return _conferenceClient;
}

-(void)conferenceClient:(OWTConferenceClient *)client didReceiveMessage:(NSString *)message from:(NSString *)senderId{
  }

- (void)conferenceClient:(OWTConferenceClient *)client didAddParticipant:(OWTConferenceParticipant *)user{
}

-(void)conferenceClient:(OWTConferenceClient *)client didAddStream:(OWTRemoteStream *)stream{
}
```

to Swift

AppDelegate:

```
func conferenceClient() -> OWTConferenceClient {  <--- Error here: Invalid redeclaration of 'conferenceClient()'

return conferenceClient
}

 func conferenceClient(_ client:OWTConferenceClient, didAdd stream:OWTRemoteStream){
}

func conferenceClient(_ client:OWTConferenceClient, didAdd user:OWTConferenceParticipant) {
}

func conferenceClient(_ client:OWTConferenceClient, didReceiveMessage message:String, from senderId:String) {
}
```

What is wrong with Swift part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you have a (global or instance) variable named `conferenceClient` which then interferes with that function.

You need to rename the variable (in ObjC, it had an underscore `_conferenceClient`)